# Nativescript translateY different on Android and iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

I am creating a [BottonShet](https://www.nuvious.com/posts/multiple-frames-in-nativescript) component  in Nativescript-Vue. The problem I have is the following:

Uploading the frame using translateY or animation behaves differently on iOS and Android.

I have a component:

In the botton sheet I have an element that is 150 high. If I apply a

> frame.translateY = Screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs  - 150

in android it reaches a high and in ios it reaches another. What's going on here? How can I calculate a height so that it is the same in all phones from 150 and the screen height?

[image]

In this [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/animations) it says that the translate of the animation is measured in DIPs so this should work well on all devices.

In the [mentioned tutorial](https://www.nuvious.com/posts/multiple-frames-in-nativescript), it makes an if to apply one height or another depending on the platform, I don't want that, I want to be able to calculate so I don't have to be testing on all devices.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this issue recently what I did was get the activity content height an used that for my calculations so now I can do `frame.translateY = activityHeight - 150`

```
get activityHeight(): number {
    if(isIOS){
      return Screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs;
    }
    const activity = Application.android.foregroundActivity || Application.android.startActivity;
    if(!activity) return 0;
    const rootView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if(!rootView) return 0;
    return rootView.getHeight() / Screen.mainScreen.scale || 0;
  }
```

Comment: Ohh this makes it perfect on Android, if I put (your method()) - 150 the container goes up just what it occupies (150) but on iOS it is still not perfect, you always have to give it a little more that I am not able to calculate . I have tried it natively with: CABasicAnimation.animationWithKeyPath but it doesn't go up to the perfect 150 either. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: For iOS you can attach to the `layoutChanged` event then with event passed u can get the size of that view e.g `event.object.getMeasuredHeight()/Screen.mainScreen.scale` (divide by the scale because `getMeasuredHeight` should be in px) you can try attaching this to the page element or whatever view u have as the main container

Comment: Is that! for some unknown reason in iOS Screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs returns 50 or 60 more than this.$refs.page.nativeView.getMeasuredHeight () / Screen.mainScreen.scale. Many thanks! I had been with this for 2 days!

Comment: if you agree, could you include this in the if part of isIOS?

Comment: `Screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs` should return more since it usually adds the status bar height to the calculation also it's always recommended to separate iOS and Android code . If you're using {N} v7+ please go for global since it uses tree shaking now so u now the final bundle should be smaller . 